# My twitter api search query is returning tuple error

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I can't get my code to return search queries on Twitter with sentiment analysis.

I can confirm the API part works. I just can't extract the text part of the tweet results which means the analysis doesn't execute.

I am learning from this video and I copied his conventions exactly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_OZdbCzHUA&index=2&list=PL2-dafEMk2A6QKz1mrk1uIGfHkC1zZ6UU

Currently I get this error:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'text'

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
public_tweets = api.search('Horizon Zero Dawn')
print(type(public_tweets))

for tweet in zip(range(10), public_tweets):
    print(tweet.text)
    analysis = textblob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis)
```

Comment: Try: `for tweet in public_tweets:`

Comment: `zip` would return a list of tuples, which means the iterable list is something like [(1,tweet_obj1),(2,tweet_obj2)...]. Hence you need something like `tweet[1].text`, as `tweet` is the whole tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tuple index to get to the tweet object

```
for tweet in zip(range(10), public_tweets):
    print(tweet[1].text)
```